# Disable notifications for a specific time period

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to disable the notifications on client's side so they don't get notifications at night (10PM to 7AM).

Server's is not aware of the timezone and the app is used worldwide so my only option is to disable notifications on the client.

I haven't seen anything that could help me to achieve that around.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The server has to do it. Make/ask for an endpoint that accepts two times, both in GMT. The client should know how to convert it's local time to GMT and the server should be able to respect the GMT time range.

Comment: But what if the user changes timezone?

Comment: When the app is in the foreground and figures out it's in a different timezone, it needs to update the server.